# Generate XML with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am new to generating XML with SQL Server.

I received a XML sample file that I need to generate from a dataset.

Here is a snippet of the requested XML format.  I'm not sure of how to accomplish this with just SQL.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

```
- <clinical-abstraction>
- <data-element id="patientnumber">
  <value>31878</value> 
  </data-element>
- <data-element id="ivddiagnosis">
  <value>445</value> 
  </data-element>
- <data-element id="dateofbirth">
  <value>06/27/1948</value> 
  </data-element>
  </clinical-abstraction>
- <clinical-abstraction>
- <data-element id="patientnumber">
  <value>29179</value> 
  </data-element>
- <data-element id="ivddiagnosis">
  <value>440.2</value> 
  </data-element>
- <data-element id="dateofbirth">
  <value>01/07/1947</value> 
  </data-element>
  </clinical-abstraction>
```

Comment: What data are you trying to generate the XML from?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to follow this pattern, replacing my example names with the proper table name and the field names for the [data-element/value] columns.

```
SELECT
  'patientnumber' AS [data-element/@id],
  patientnumber AS [data-element/value],
  '',
  'ivddiagnosis' AS [data-element/@id],
  ivddiagnosis AS [data-element/value],
  '',
  'dateofbirth' AS [data-element/@id],
  dateofbirth AS [data-element/value]
FROM
  Patient
FOR XML PATH
  ('clinical-abstraction')
```

"[FOR XML PATH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx)" complains if your query is ambiguous, so you need to supply [columns without a name](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510469.aspx) to organize the elements and attributes correctly.  The string in the parentheses is the name you give the row, represented as the outermost element in the XML (aside from a root, which you didn't specify).

Comment: Thank you Mugo!  That works perfectly.  I had struggled for 3 days on this.  I really appreciate your help.  Thank you again.

Comment: @user3700880 You're welcome.  Your question suggested that you were simply stuck in a non-intuitive area with no way out, and you provided enough info for me to make a guess as to what might be helpful to you.  I've been there myself.